# How to use redirect transform when coding a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, browser-extension

I am trying to make an extension that redirects all reddit links to old reddit version but when I try it nothing happens (the link just gets opened in the new reddit domain not the .old one)

my `manifest.json`:

```
  "name": "OldREddit",
  "action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "icons": { 
    "16": "icon.png",
    "48": "icon.png",
    "128": "icon.png" },
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Do not like the new reddit UI? This extension turns all new reddit links to old.reddit domain",
  "declarative_net_request" : {
  "rule_resources" : [{
    "id": "ruleset",
    "enabled": true,
    "path": "rules_1.json"
  }]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "declarativeNetRequest"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "*://old.reddit.com/*",
    "*://reddit.com/*"
  ]
}
```

and here is my `rules_1.json`:

```
  "id": 1,
  "priority": 1,
  "action": {
    "type": "redirect",
    "redirect": {
      "transform": { "scheme": "https", "host": "old.reddit.com" }
    }
  },
  "condition": { "urlFilter": "||reddit.com", "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"] }
}]
```

Comment: The code seems fine, but it may cause an infinite recursion since it matches the target domain as well, so it's better to use `|https://www.reddit.com/` - there is no `http` for reddit AFAIK and it always has `www` (Chrome just [hides it](https://superuser.com/a/1498561)), also note the last `/` which is always present in the real internal URL as it denotes the end of the host name in order not to match a possible phishing site like `reddit.com.uk`.

Comment: ok than I don't know what is wrong with my computer and thanks for the advice!